BIM 360 3L Authentication Failed Autodesk API Integration
I am trying to authenticate BIM 360 in Autodesk Navisworks Manage 2023. having this error.
3L Authentication Failed: Exception of type 'Autodesk.consulting.aos.api.core.exceptions.apsAuthenticationException' was thrown
Change the application port to http://localhost:8787/oauth/ but it didn't work.

The information you provided is limited. Could you please confirm if you are following the steps outlined in the link below?
https://www.autodesk.com/support/technical/article/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-open-files-in-Navisworks-from-BIM-360-and-the-Autodesk-Construction-Cloud-Platform.html
Furthermore, could you share a detailed step-by-step outline of the process you've followed on your end?
The more details you provide, the better I’ll be able to understand your issue and assist you effectively.
